# bibtex issue -- get errors in Overleaf

Tags: bibtex

I'm trying to reference a .bib file but I'm getting this error in Overleaf. Any ideas on what to do? I'm pretty sure I'm using the correct commands.

```
\bibliographystyle{plain} 

\bibliography{bibexercise}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Have you used any `\cite{}` commands?

Comment: The error says you have not used `\cite` if that is the case, you should use `\cite` to reference the whichever documents you need to reference.

Answer (score 1):

In the log, the line

```
I found no \citation commands---while reading file main.aux
```

means that you have not used the `\cite{}` command in the source text.
Try adding at least one.